# Adding a custom python layer in caffe2

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, caffe2

Adding a python layer in caffe was fairly straightforward (creating a child class that inherits from caffe.layer and adding four basic methods, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344168/what-is-a-python-layer-in-caffe/41452702#41452702) and [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pycaffe/layers/pyloss.py). However, adding a custom python layer in caffe2 is not as straightforward to me. Can someone please explain the procedure for adding a python layer in caffe2?

Comment: A caffe2 issue that refers to an example that might help:
https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/issues/366

Answer (score 0):

First, you must implement your new layer as a Python class as shown in the example. In this case, it only outputs the input tensor in reverse order:

```
class ReverseOrderOp(object):
    def forward(self, inputs, outputs):
        blob_out = outputs[0]

        blob_out.reshape(inputs[0].shape)
        blob_out.data[...] = inputs[0].data[::-1]
```

Then, you can add your new layer to the model using `model.net.Python`:

```
model = ModelHelper(name="test")

l = np.asarray([0,1,2,3])
workspace.FeedBlob('l', l.astype(np.float32))

model.net.Python(ReverseOrderOp().forward)(
    ['l'], ['out'], name='ReverseOrder'
)
workspace.RunNetOnce(model.net)
print(workspace.FetchBlob('out'))
```

The output should be `[ 3.  2.  1.  0.]`