# How to feed several LMDB files to the data layer in Caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a very big dataset and it is not a good idea to convert it to a single LMDB file for Caffe. Thus, I am trying to split it into small parts and specify a TXT file containing the paths to the corresponding LMDB files.
Here's an example of my data layer:

```
layer {
name: "data"
type: "Data"
top: "data"
top: "label"
include {
phase: TRAIN
}
data_param {
source: "path/to/lmdb.txt"
batch_size: 256
backend: LMDB
  }
}
```

And this is my lmdb.txt file:

```
/path/to/train1lmdb
/path/to/train2lmdb
/path/to/train3lmdb
```

However, I got the following error:

```
I0828 10:30:40.639502 26950 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer data
F0828 10:30:40.639549 26950 db_lmdb.hpp:15] Check failed: mdb_status == 0 
(20 vs. 0) Not a directory
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
@     0x7f678e4a3daa  (unknown)
@     0x7f678e4a3ce4  (unknown)
@     0x7f678e4a36e6  (unknown)
@     0x7f678e4a6687  (unknown)
@     0x7f678ebee5e1  caffe::db::LMDB::Open()
@     0x7f678eb2b7d4  caffe::DataLayer<>::DataLayer()
@     0x7f678eb2b982  caffe::Creator_DataLayer<>()
@     0x7f678ec1a1a9  caffe::Net<>::Init()
@     0x7f678ec1c382  caffe::Net<>::Net()
@     0x7f678ec2e200  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
@     0x7f678ec2f153  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
@     0x7f678ec2f42f  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
@     0x7f678eabcc71  caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
@           0x40f18e  caffe::SolverRegistry<>::CreateSolver()
@           0x40827d  train()
@           0x405bec  main
@     0x7f678ccfaf45  (unknown)
@           0x4064f3  (unknown)
@              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So, how can I make it work? Is this kind of method feasible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem:**
You are confusing `"Data"` layer and [`"HDF5Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5data.html) layer:
With [`"Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/data.html) layer you can only specify **one** lmdb/leveldb dataset, and your `source:` entry should point to the only database you are using.
On the other hand, with [`"HDF5Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5data.html) layer you can have **multiple** binary `hdf5` files, and the `source:` parameter points to a *text* file listing all the binary files you are about to use.

**Solutions**
0. (Following [PrzemekD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911219/how-to-feed-several-lmdb-files-to-the-data-layer-in-caffe/45912426?noredirect=1#comment78787095_45912426)'s comment) Add **different** [`"Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/data.html) layer for each lmdb you have (with smaller `batch_size`) and then use [`"Concat"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/concat.html) layer to "merge" the different inputs into a single minibatch.
1. As you can already guess, one solution is to convert your data to hdf5 binary format and use [`"HDF5Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5data.html) layer.
2. Alternatively, you can write your own [`"Python"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481539/1714410) input layer, this layer should be able to read from all lmdb file (using python lmdb interface) and feed the data, batch by batch to your net.

Comment: How about solution 3: have multiple data layers, each loading from a single LMDB, and then concat?

Comment: @PrzemekD `"Concat"` in the batch-size dimension. That's a nice idea!

Comment: Will it lead to the out-of-memory problem if I load several LMDBs at a time since my dataset is too big? @PrzemekD

Comment: @Y.C.Sun caffe does not load all the lmdb into memory. It only reads batch by batch.

Comment: Thx for your help!@Shai