# Is there a layer in Caffe that can get an arbitrary sub block in a blob?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

Is there a layer in Caffe that can get an arbitrary sub block in a blob?

Comment: haha...frequently asking

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is not a completely general slicing layer in caffe.
If you want to extract sub-blocks that are specific channels of a blob, you can use [`"Slice"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/slice.html) layer.
Depending on your requirements, you might find [`"Crop"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/crop.html) layer sufficient for your needs.
If you need more flexible access to sub-blocks, you might want to consider using a [`"Python"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481539/1714410) layer.

---

**An example using `"Crop"` layer**
As you [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139309/is-there-a-layer-in-caffe-that-can-get-an-arbitrary-sub-block-in-a-blob/46140788?noredirect=1#comment79346261_46140788) `"Crop"` layer expects two "bottom"s but since the second one is only used for reference shape, you can produce it using [`"DummyData"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/dummydata.html) layer.
Suppose you want to select `x[:,:,3:20,5:40]`, this is a 17x35 crop

```
layer {
  name: "ref_shape_17x35"
  type: "DummyData"
  top: "ref_shape_17x35"
  dummy_data_param { shape { dim: 1 dim: 1 dim: 17 dim: 35 } }
}
layer {
   name: "crop_x"
   type: "Crop"
   bottom: "x"
   bottom: "ref_shape_17x35"
   top: "crop_x"
   crop_param {
     axis: 2  # do not crop the first two dimensions
     offset: 3
     offset: 5
   }
 }
```

I did not try it myself, but it should work (let me know if it doesn't).

Comment: But the crop layer must have two input, mustn't it?