# How can I start writing the code for my layer?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe

I have seen that researchers are adding some functionalities to the original version of Caffe and use those layers and functionalities according to what they need and then these versions are shared through `Github`. If I am not mistaken, there are two ways: `1)` by recompiling Caffe after adding c++ and Cuda versions of layers. `2)` writing a python code for the functionality and call it as python layer in Caffe.

I want to add a new layer to Caffe based on my research problem. I really do not from which point should I start writing the new layer and which steps I should consider.

My questions are:

1) Is there any documentation or any learning materials that I can use it for writing the layer?

2) Which way of above-mentioned methods of adding a new layer is preferred?

I really appreciate any help and guidance

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For research purposes, for "playing around", it is usually more convenient to write a python layer: saves you the hustle of compiling etc.
You can find a short tutorial on `"Python"` layer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481539/1714410).

On the other hand, if you want better performance you should write a native c++ code for your layer.
You can find a short explanation about it [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Development).

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance