# Save output images in Caffe

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am very new to using the caffe framework. I have a network which works on images. It takes images as input and outputs images. Does caffe have a layer I have to include so as to save the output images?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Caffe doesn't have a "save-to-image" layer.
You can try and see if [`"HDF5Output"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5output.html) layer can work for you: you can save your output image as a floating-point ND array into hdf5 binary file and read it later with other applications.

Alternatively, you can use a [`"Python"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41344168/1714410) layer to save the images for you. Just write the save code in python (using `PIL.Image` package for example).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would it make sense to try and read the blob data from a deconvolution layer and save that?

Comment: @user3126802 I don't know what your are trying to do. As long as it makes sense to you - you are welcome to try and do it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I was reading up about the HDFOutput layer. However a problem may arise, since it would try to create the same file for each iteration.

Comment: @user3126802 I'm afraid I do not have any experience with `"HDF5Output"` layer, I did hear about issues people had using this layer. I suspect it would be easier to use a `"Python"` layer for this task.