# How to train a FCN network while the size of images are not fixed and they are varying?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation

I have already trained the [FCN model](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org) with fixed size images 256x256. Could I ask from experts how can I train the same model once the size of image are changing from one image to another image?

I really appreciate your advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose one of these strategies:

#### 1. Batch = 1 image

By training each image as a different batch, you can `reshape` the net in the `forward()` (rather than in `reshape()`) of the data layer, thus changing the net at each iteration.
+write `reshape` once in `forward` method and you no longer need to worry about input shapes and sizes.

-`reshape`ing the net often requires allocation/deallocation of CPU/GPU memory and therefore it takes time.
-You might find a single image in a batch to be too small of a batch.

For example (assuming you are using a [`"Python"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481539/1714410) layer for input):

```
def reshape(self, bottom, top):
  pass  # you do not reshape here.

def forward(self, bottom, top):
  top[0].data.reshape( ... )  # reshape the blob - this will propagate the reshape to the rest of the net at each iteration
  top[1].data.reshape( ... )  # 

  # feed the data to the net      
  top[0].data[...] = current_img
  top[1].data[...] = current_label
```

#### 2. Random crops

You can decide on a fixed input size and then randomly crop all input images (and the corresponding ground truths).
+No need to `reshape` every iteration (faster).
+Control over model size during train.

-Need to implement random crops for images and labels

#### 3. Fixed size

Resize all images to the same size (like in SSD).
+Simple

-Images are distorted if not all images have the same aspect ratio.
-You are no invariant to scale

Comment: Thank a lot for your help, should I add reshape layer after `Data` layer and before `Convolution` layer for both `data` and `label`? Is the following layer correct if `height` and `width` are changing?` layer {
  name: "my_reshape"
  type: "Reshape"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "reshape_in"
  reshape_param { shape: {dim: 0 dim: 0 dim: -1 dim: -1 } }
}`

Comment: Could I ask how can I change `deploy.prototxt`?

Comment: @S.EB your data layer should do that for you. in the code you linked there is a python layer that handles inputs

Comment: Sir, could you please explain the first option more? I thought you are mentioning [Reshape Layer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/reshape.html). Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Could I ask one more question? Where should I place the `Python` Layer in the model definition, after `Data` layers? apologies for asking lots of questions. Thanks once again

Comment: I assumed the `"Python"` layer **replaces** the `"Data"` layer. Coming to think of it. If you build an `lmdb` with images/labels I suppose you can have a different size for each image and then the `"Data"` layer handles everything for you (I haven't tried it myself).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try and post it here.

Comment: @Shai: Crazy enough, in the past year I somehow used all of these methods!

Comment: @Shai: I mostly used (3), but now I'm developing a new model that samples data from a single image only (like Mask R-CNN), so switched to (1)

Comment: @Shai: it seems that even when minibatch=1, validation size image has to be the same size as train: otherwise fully connected layers report an error: Input size incompatible with inner product parameters.

Comment: @Shai: good point. Unfortunately I didn't find a better way to make a prediction

Comment: @Alex look at net_surgery tutorial: they convert innerproduct layer to conv layer. you can predict from conv outputs as well